# Why order of serializing a lambda expression containing a cirular-self-reference matters and can throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, classcastexception, circular-reference

`ClassCastException` is thrown by java8 when a lambda expression which contains a cirular reference via its expression arguments to itself, is deserialized.

The exception only is thrown when the lambda is serialized before the object creating the circular reference.

Tested on openjdk version "1.8.0_292" and "11.0.14.1". Please find test code on how to reproduce:

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestLambdaSerialization
{
    interface SerRunnable extends Runnable, Serializable
    {
    }

    static class A implements Serializable
    {
        SerRunnable runnable;

        A()
        {
            runnable = () -> System.out.println(this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        A a = new A();
        serializeDeserialize(a);
        serializeDeserialize(a.runnable);
    }

    public static void serializeDeserialize(Object o1) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.printf("Starting object %s%n", o1);
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream outBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(outBytes)) {
            out.writeObject(o1);
            out.flush();
            try (ByteArrayInputStream inBytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(outBytes.toByteArray());
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inBytes)) {
                Object o2 = in.readObject();
                System.out.printf("Deserialized object %s%n", o2);
            }
            catch (ClassCastException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.8.0_292
Starting object TestLambdaSerialization$A@b4c966a
Deserialized object TestLambdaSerialization$A@7106e68e
Starting object TestLambdaSerialization$A$$Lambda$1/1480010240@34a245ab
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field TestLambdaSerialization$A.runnable of type TestLambdaSerialization$SerRunnable in instance of TestLambdaSerialization$A
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2301)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2411)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2093)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1655)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at TestLambdaSerialization.serializeDeserialize(TestLambdaSerialization.java:36)
    at TestLambdaSerialization.main(TestLambdaSerialization.java:24)
```

Deserialization of object **a** doesn't throw the exception, when the lambda expression is the starting point a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

Does the order of serialization in case of lambda expressions matter? If yes is there a workaround beside avoiding lambda (replacing them by anonymous inner class)?

Comment: Seems like serializing lambda expressions is [strongly discouraged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#serialization), just like [inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#serialization), because of the dynamic creation of synthetic constructs (as the tutorial reads). If you replace `this` in the body of your lambda with for example the empty string, then running your code yields a different class on deserialization, than the one serialized...